# Check whether address path is available

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Sorry, it might be duplicated post. is there a way can javascript/jquery to detect whether the url link is available or not ?? for instances, detect `http://www.thisissample.com/` is not available and return false, if `https://www.google.com.my/` is available and return true.

Comment: why not just making a request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, since you could run into problems if making an ajax request because of cross-domain restrictions, another strategy would be trying to load the url into a script tag, which does accept other domains. Here is what your code would look like:

```
function checkURL(url) { 
    var scriptTag = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("script"));
    scriptTag.onload = function() {
        alert( url + " is available");
    };
    scriptTag.onerror = function() {
        alert( url + " is not available");
    };
    scriptTag.src = url;
}
```

Comment: Wow.. it's worked! sorry, if there a limitation for this ?

Comment: This should work fine in all modern browsers. The cross-domain limitation would only happen if you tried to make an ajax request.

Comment: @user3835327 : There is a major limitation to this approach : both `onload` and `onerror` are triggered asynchronously. If you want `checkURL()` to return true or false, you'll need to do a bit more tweaking.

Comment: @JohnSlegers thank for the suggestion, will look into it :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use XHR and see if it responds a 404 Not Found or not. Please read [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) for HTTP Status Code.

Please try this code :

```
<script>
    function checkURL(url){
        var reader = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var checkFor = url;
        reader.open('get', checkFor, true);
        reader.onreadystatechange = checkReadyState;
        function checkReadyState() {
            if (reader.readyState === 4) {
                if ((reader.status == 200) || (reader.status == 0)) {
                    //document.location.href = checkFor;
                    alert("Page exist !!!");
                }
                else if(request.status === 404) {  
                    alert("Not Found");
                }
                else {
                    alert("Status Code : " + reader.status);
                }

            }
        }
        reader.send(null);
    }
</script>
<body onload="checkURL('http://www.mozill.org/');">
</body>
```

Please notice that it will only work on the **same** origin. For another host, you can use a server-side language to do that. Like this below :

```
<?php
    $url = parse_url('https://www.mozilla.org/');

    $host = $url['host'];
    $port = 80;
    $path = $url['path'];
    $query = (!empty($url['query'])?$url['query']:null);

    $request = "HEAD $path?$query HTTP/1.1\r\n"
              ."Host: $host\r\n"
              ."Connection: close\r\n"
              ."\r\n";

    $address = gethostbyname($host);
    $socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
    socket_connect($socket, $address, $port);
    socket_write($socket, $request, strlen($request));
    $response = split(' ', socket_read($socket, 1024));

    if($response[1] >= 200 && $response[1] < 300){
        print "<p>Response: ".$response[1]." - Success URL exist !!!</p>\r\n";
    }
    else if($response[1] >= 300 && $response[1] < 400){
        print "<p>Response: ".$response[1]." - Redirection</p>\r\n";
    }
    else if($response[1] >= 400 && $response[1] < 500){
        print "<p>Response: ".$response[1]." - Client Error</p>\r\n";
    }
    else if($response[1] >= 500){
        print "<p>Response: ".$response[1]." - Server Error</p>\r\n";
    }
    socket_close($socket);
?>
```

Hope this help you out...